# Java Mac how to create an about window like finder's

Tags: java, macos, menuitem, menubar

I am programmi an application for mac and I would like to have an about window to show to the user some infos, like the one of Finder.

Actually I am using this code:

```
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
// SET NAME IN THE MACMENUBAR
System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", Constants.APP_NAME);  
Application application = Application.getApplication();
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("res/logo.png");
application.setDockIconImage(image);
application.setAboutHandler(new AboutHandler() {
public void handleAbout(AboutEvent arg0) {

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some infos.");
}
});;
```

but the thing that I obtain is not what I want, because is a dialog box with the "logo.png" image on the left and the text on the right. And also a big awful "OK" button that you must press to close the window.

How can I make a simple about window like Finder's ?

Can you help me? I found many tutorial on the net, but all are using deprecated methods in Application class.

(sorry for my bad english, I am italian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1. Create a `JPanel` (possibly your own subclass) and layout the components in it as you want. Then show it with `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` by passing it as the first argument, rather than passing `null` as you have.
2. Create a `JDialog` and layout the components yourself. Again, you may want to create a subclass of `JDialog` to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please tell me why is better to create a subclass rather than use a JFrame (or any other component) as object? I read many example in the net all showing a subclass that extend the Swing Component class, but I could not find a reason to that.

Comment: @Gianmarco I find that subclassing allows me to organize my code better. I often will subclass `JPanel` and layout components in the constructor of my new class. I can also add other logic in member methods as needed. Also, this allows me to reuse the `JPanel` inside of a `JFrame`, `JDialog`, `JApplet`, etc. depending on how I want to display it.

Comment: thank you! I understood!
surfing the net I found an example that extends a JDialog, but inside there is a JOptionBox. Can I put what I want in a JDialog? if yes, what's the difference between JDialog and JFrame?

Comment: @Gianmarco Yes, you can put whatever you wish inside `JDialog`. AFAIK, the main difference is that a `JDialog` is often modal, meaning that the user must dismiss it before interacting with the rest of your app. Usually, a `JFrame` is a window that doesn't block interaction with other windows.

Comment: accepted, I read something about Dialog, but i understood there's no way to have a Dialog without buttons, at least it must have an "ok" button, right? I think, the better way maybe is to create a JFrame and make it visible on top of the main frame, is that correct?

Comment: @Gianmarco I'm not sure where you read that, but I from what I can find, there is no such requirement. I would suggest reading the [Java Tutorial trail on dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and check out the [Java API docs for JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html). Then make a simple Java program that displays a dialog with a "Hello, World" label, for example.